# Associativty of Cellular product

Tags: algebraic-topology

The cellular product of cochains can be defined by composing the maps:

$$C^*(X)\otimes C^*(X)\rightarrow C^*(X\times X) \rightarrow C^*(X)$$

The first map is the standard isomorphism of tensor and cross product and the second is the map induced by the cellular appoximation of the diagonal.

Is this product associative on the level of cochains?

In Kirik and Davis there is a proof that the cup product is associative on the level on cohomology classes. But the proof uses some theory of acyclic models which i dont fully understand. If the product is indeed associative in the cellular chain complex does anyone have a simple explanation as to why? If not does anyone have a counterexample?